# ¿porque gulp-imagemin no me funcina?

Tags: gulp

```js
const {series,src,dest,watch} = require("gulp");
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");

// Funcion que compila sass



function css() {
  return src("src/scss/app.scss").pipe(sass({
    outputStyle:"expanded"
  }))
  .pipe(dest("./build/css"));
}

function minificarcss() {
  return src("src/scss/app.scss").pipe(sass({
    outputStyle:"compressed"
  })).pipe(dest("./build/css"));

}

function imagenes() {
  return src("src/img/**/*")
  .pipe(imagemin())
  .pipe(dest("./build/img"));
}



function watchArchivo() {
  watch("src/scss/**/*.scss",css);// * = la carpeta actual - ** = Todos los archivos con esa extensionCsss
}

exports.css = css;
exports.minificarcss = minificarcss;
exports.imagenes = imagenes;
exports.watchArchivo = watchArchivo;
```

este es mi gulpfile de mi proyecto ,pero cuando quiero ejecutar gulp imagenes
me sale este error:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\musicaRock\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\musicaRock\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js from C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\musicaRock\gulpfile.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\musicaRock\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\package.json.

```
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:13)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\musicaRock\gulpfile.js:3:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12) {
```

code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

he buscado por todas partes la solucion pero no me aprece nada y intentado con muchas formas para solucinar el problema pero no he tenido exito,me gustaria un poco ayuda para resolver este problema gracias

Comment: muchas gracias mi amigo , cambie la version y si me funciono  gracias

Comment: ¡Hola!, mira te cuento, actualmente el proyecto de imagemin ya no es mantenido, siendo v8.0.0 la última versión oficial, el mismo [creador](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/385) ha sostenido que no tiene ni el tiempo ni el interés por seguir aportando al proyecto y a su vez recomienda el uso de [Squoosh](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh) como remplazo de imagemin, si deseas más información puedes checar [esta issue](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/380) que se dio recientemente, en ella entenderás como es que el problema ha afectado a otras personas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro, acabo de resolver el mismo problema (tambien estoy haciendo el curso xd),
yo borre del package.json el 'gulp-imagemin' y volvi a instalar esto: npm i -D gulp-imagemin@7.0.0  es una version mas vieja, esto lo saque de las respuestas del curso, me acaba de funcionar, me paso algo parecido con la version de sass, tuve que emparchar, espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

siguiendo la respuesta de hernan

1. borre la carpeta `gulp-imegemin` dentro de la carpeta `node_modules`
2. ejecute la instalacion, pero con la diferencia que la ejecute como
   dependencia de desarrollo

   ```
   npm install --save-dev gulp-imagemin@7.0.0
   ```
3. volvi a ejecutar `gulp imagenes` y funciono....

Answer (score 0):

Ya que la versión de imagemin 8 ahora es ESM puro, ([Nota del autor al respecto](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)) si deseas usarlo en el sistema de módulos de commonjs, deberás cargarlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
const imageminJpegtran = require('imagemin-jpegtran');

async function main() {
  const imagemin = (await import('imagemin')).default;
  const files = await imagemin(['images/*.{jpg,png}'], {
    destination: 'build/images',
    plugins: [imageminJpegtran()]
  });
}

main();
```

Recomiendo no usar las versiones antiguas de estos plugins, ya que la mayoría tienen dependencias con vulnerabilidades criticas de seguridad.